# How to plot data on a cylindrical grid using slice?

Tags: matlab, sorting, 3d, cylindrical

I have input data on a cylindrical grid and want to plot them using `slice` in MATLAB.
To do this I first transform the reference coordinates into Cartesian coordinates using `pol2cart`.

```
r   = linspace(1,4,4);
phi = linspace(0,2*pi,10);
z   = linspace(1,3,3);

[rmesh,phimesh,zmesh]=meshgrid(r,phi,z)
[xmesh,ymesh,zmesh]=pol2cart(phimesh,rmesh,zmesh)
```

When I use `slice` now (e.g. `slice(xmesh,ymesh,zmesh,ones(10,4,3),2,2,2)`) an error is thrown, because the coordinate matrices are not ordered correctly (`Input grid is not a valid MESHGRID.`)

How can I modify the matrices to get a plottable result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly you cannot use data given in cylindrical coordinates for usage with slice.

From the matlab documentation:

```
slice(X,Y,Z,V,sx,sy,sz) draws slices of the volume V. X, Y, and Z are three-dimensional arrays specifying the coordinates for V.
X, Y, and Z must be monotonic and orthogonally spaced (as if produced by the function meshgrid).
```

What you can do is use `griddata`.

here is an example:

```
    r = linspace(1,4,4);
    phi = linspace(0,2*pi,10);
    z   = linspace(1,3,3);
    data = repmat(linspace(1,0,4),[10,1,3]);

    [rmesh,phimesh,zmesh]=meshgrid(r,phi,z);
    [xmesh,ymesh,zmesh]=pol2cart(phimesh,rmesh,zmesh);

    [xg, yg, zg] = meshgrid(linspace(-4,4,50),linspace(-4,4,50),linspace(1,3,3));
    gdata = griddata(xmesh,ymesh,zmesh,data,xg,yg,zg);

    slice(xg,yg,zg,gdata,2,2,2)
```

Depending on what kind of data you have and how important it is not to display data that is 'out of bounds' (meaning, following your example: of radius smaller than 1 or larger than 4) you can add the following to hide data that is out of your area of interest:

```
rg = sqrt(xg.^2+yg.^2);
gdataNaN = gdata;
gdataNaN(rg<min(r)) = NaN;
gdataNaN(rg>max(r)) = NaN;

figure
slice(xg,yg,zg,gdataNaN,2,2,2)
```

If that isn't enough you would have to implement your own `slice` method (basically using the griddata method) or look on matlab central fileexchange.
I haven't tested it, but tools for analyzing MRI images might do the trick (check, for example, this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27983-3d-slicer ).

EDIT:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30147-smartslice-and-igslice
this seems to have been developed by someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just call meshgrid on the Cartesian coordinates?

```
r   = linspace(1,4,4);
phi = linspace(0,2*pi,10);
z   = linspace(1,3,3);

[x, y] = pol2cart(r,phi);

[xmesh,ymesh,zmesh]=meshgrid(x, y, z);
```

btw sometimes you might find `[ymesh,xmesh,zmesh]=meshgrid(x, y, z);` makes more sense for your application.

Comment: This leads to an error `Matrix dimensions must agree.` in `pol2cart`.

Comment: ok what about using your original code but adding this line at the end: [xmesh,ymesh,zmesh]=meshgrid(xmesh(:,1,1), ymesh(1,:,1), zmesh(1,1,:)) i.e. recreate the grids?

Comment: This changes the matrices (because each column AND row in xmesh and ymesh is different). It does however change the error message to `The grid was created from grid vectors that were not strictly monotonic increasing.`, which implies that sorting is not enough, but that the grid must really be made of grid vectors (copied along the other dimensions). This is not possible in my case, so it seems pointless to try to sort the matrices. Thank you anyway!