# How can I convert from cylindrical to cartesian coordinates in 3D for plotting in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, coordinates, reshape

I am trying to define a function in [3D cylindrical coorindates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) in Matlab, and then to convert it to 3D cartesian for plotting purposes.

[image]

For example, if my function depends only on the radial coordinate r (let's say linearly for simplicity), I can plot a 3D isosurface at the value f = 70 like the following:

```matlab
x = linspace(-10,10,100);
y = linspace(-10,10,100);
z = linspace(-2,2,100);

[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
R = sqrt( X.^2 + Y.^2 ); % Calculate the radius for each [x,y] coordinate pair

f = 100*R; % Calculate the function f, dependent only on the radius

isosurface(X,Y,Z,f,70);
```

[image]

However, since the function depends only on r, I should be able to instead define a vector for the r coordinate only, and calculate f based on that instead:

```matlab
r = 0:0.1:1 ;   % define radial coordinate
f = 100*r ;     % make the function linearly dependent on radial coorindate for simplicity
```

My aim is now to plot an isosurface based only on knowing r and f. I would like to specify a vector of z and theta coordinates, maybe like this

```matlab
z = linspace(-2,2,100);
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,50);
```

and use these together with r to generate [x,y,z] coordinates. In addition, f now is a 1D array instead of a 3D array like the first example, so somehow f needs to be reshaped?

The reason for this is because I am trying to do manipulations on f inside a loop many times, and with the first case this results in many operations over a 3D matrix, which is too slow. I would like to instead perform operations on the 1D vector, and generate 3D version only for plotting.

I hope my question is clear. I don't think the [pol2cart](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pol2cart.html) function does what I want, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a rather dificult task to represent 4D data. You mention you want to visualize 4D data with the [isosurface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html) function. Another alternative is to represent the 4th variable using a color scale, with the [slice](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html) function.

The problem with these functions is that they work for the cartesian coordinates [X,Y,Z].
What you have to do is to interpolate your data to your domain in cartesian coordinates, before using the functions to represent these 4D data, as in [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/355776-using-slice-on-a-cartesian-grid-that-was-generated-in-cylindrical-coordinates) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316603/how-to-plot-data-on-a-cylindrical-grid-using-slice).

Essentially, what you end up with is:

```
% generate mesh in cylindrical coordinates
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,50);
r = 0:0.1:1;
z = linspace(-2,2,100);

[Theta,R,Z] = meshgrid(theta,r,z);

% Evaluate function in cylindrical coordinates
f = 100*r; % f is function only of radial coordinate
f = f'; % make sure f is column vector
f = repmat(f,1,length(theta),length(z)); % f must be 3D matrix to plot surface

% transform to cartesian coordinates
[X,Y,Z] = pol2cart(Theta,R,Z)

[xg, yg, zg] = meshgrid(linspace(-1,1,20),linspace(-1,1,20),linspace(-2.1,2.1,20));

Px = squeeze(X);
Py = squeeze(Y);
Pz = squeeze(Z);
v = squeeze(f);
F = scatteredInterpolant([Px(:) Py(:) Pz(:)],v(:),'linear','nearest');

f_interp = F(xg,yg,zg);
```

And now you can use whatever function you want to visualize the 4D data:

```
isosurface(xg,yg,zg,f_interp,70);
```

You can interpolate your data with either the [scatteredinterpolant](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html) function or the [griddata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) function, whatever fits best to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, you have still evaluated the function by using R as a 3D matrix. However, I would like to evaluate the function on a lower dimensional array as in my second example (this is because in my real code the function evaluation is quite computationally intensive). Can you provide an example where f is evaluated on the 1D array?

Comment: Just evaluate the function on the `r` array and then [repmat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) the results to create the 3D array. Check my update.

Comment: Hi @Thales, the code does not run. I get an error "The size of X must match the size of V or the number of columns of V" when trying to execute the isosurface. f_interp is 20x20x20 but X,Y and Z are 11x50x100.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You should isosurface the variables `xg`, `yg` and `zg` - the ones you used to interpolate the data. I edited the answer

Comment: Thank you - I think I was hoping there was a way to do it without interpolation, but your answer has made it clear for me that it seems not. Thanks for your help!